# Why does Beautiful Soup not return the content?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am using bs4 to scrape some results. I could see the HTML content in the source but when I try to fetch it using bs4, it does not give rather says "File does not exist"

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get("https://result.smitcs.in/grade.php?subid=BA1106")    
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, "html.parser")

marks_pre = soup.find("pre")
marks = marks_pre.find("div")

print(marks.prettify())
```

The above code returns

```html
<div style="font-family: courier; line-height: 12px;font-size:
20px;background:white;">  File does not exist </div>
```

The above code works fine if I copy the source code from the web and save it locally as HTML file and then fetch it.

Comment: not sure if it's a typo or a mistake but `source` should be defined before `soup`

Comment: I *do* get "File does not exists" – and in Courier, too – in my browser so your code seems to be working correctly after all. (Apart from the fact that your code does not work, that is.)

Comment: What did you expect to get instead?

Comment: @David check the following answer is working for you or not?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = "https://result.smitcs.in/grade.php?subid=BA1106"
PAGE = requests.get(URL)

# get HTML content
SOUP = BeautifulSoup(PAGE.content, 'lxml')

marks = SOUP.find("div")

print(marks.prettify())
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is better?

Comment: @mkrieger1 in question code, you give obviously giving an error `NameError: name 'source' is not defined` because you use source before assign

Comment: you can read the documentation of BeautifulSoup https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/